# Efficiency of for loop statements

Tags: plsql

In pl/sql, it's possible to do:

```
begin

  for i in (select colname from table)
  loop
     dbms_output.put_line(i.colname);
  end loop;

end;
```

which will loop through the results set generated by the sql query in the loop declaration. However, is this inefficient? Does this result in the SQL being executed on every iteration? If so, does the following solve the issue?

```
declare

TYPE name_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
all_names name_typ;

begin

  select col_name BULK COLLECT INTO all_names from mytable;

  for i in 1..all_names.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(all_names(i));
  end loop;

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1) Is this inefficient?
```

Sort of. It's inefficient compared to direct SQL .. if you can do it in SQL, don't do it PL/SQL.
   That said, what you have as a cursor structure is sound and about as "efficient" as it gets (barring BULK collect as you got into later)

```
2) Does this result in the SQL being executed on every iteration?
```

No. It's a cursor, it fires up once, and just keep polling for the results.

```
3) If so, does the following solve the issue?
```

It doesn't really change anything in regards to the QUERY .. the BULK collect is just improving things in the retrieval of the rows.

Rather than retrieving 1 row and saying "Ok .. got it" .. it's grabbing 20, 50 or 100 at a time .. then turning to the client "Got them!"

So in that regard, the BULK collect is a bit more efficient.

Again, I'll say: If you can do it in SQL, do so . :) SQL will almost always trump PL/SQL ... BULK collect or not ..

This is a nice article by Tom Kyte on the subject (and others) ;)
(although he doesn't mention BULK collect in this particular article)

[Tom Kyte article on SQL, cursors, etc.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o27asktom-084983.html)

He repeats his "mantra" here, over the BULK collect option ;)

[Tom's mantra](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:760210800346068768)

In case those links eventually break .. his "mantra" is:

```
o You should do it in a single SQL statement if at all possible. 
o If you cannot do it in a single SQL Statement, then do it in PL/SQL. 
o If you cannot do it in PL/SQL, try a Java Stored Procedure. 
o If you cannot do it in Java, do it in a C external procedure. 
o If you cannot do it in a C external routine, you might want to seriously think about why it is you need to do it
```

Comment: Thanks! The question came about because of a much longer pl/sql script, so this particular example does need to be in pl/sql, but the point about doing stuff in a single query is good

Comment: PL/SQL's cursor for loop does bulk collect limit 100 behind the scenes now. (As of 10g or 11g, forget which.)